# Python: Problem with list editing

Tags: python, list

Simplified version of my code:

```
sequence = [['WT_1', 'AAAAAAAA'], ['WT_2', 'BBBBBBB']]

def speciate(sequence):
    lineage_1 = []
    lineage_2 = []

    for i in sequence:
        lineage_1.append(i)
    for k in sequence:
        lineage_2.append(k)

    lineage_1[0][0] = 'L1_A'
    lineage_1[1][0] = 'L1_B'
    lineage_2[0][0] = 'L2_A'
    lineage_2[1][0] = 'L2_B'

    print lineage_1
    print lineage_2

speciate(sequence)
```

outputs:

```
[['L2_A', 'AAAAAAAA'], ['L2_B','BBBBBBB']]
[['L2_A','AAAAAAAA'], ['L2_B','BBBBBBB']]
```

when I would expect to get this:

```
[['L1_A', 'AAAAAAAA'], ['L1_B','BBBBBBB']]
[['L2_A','AAAAAAAA'], ['L2_B','BBBBBBB']]
```

Does anybody know what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are appending list objects in your for-loops -- the **same** list object (`sequence[0]`).

So when you modify the first element of that list:

```
lineage_1[0][0] = 'L1_A'
lineage_1[1][0] = 'L1_B'
lineage_2[0][0] = 'L2_A'
lineage_2[1][0] = 'L2_B'
```

you're seeing it show up as modified in both the `lineage_X` lists that contain copies of the list that is in `sequence[0]`.

Do something like:

```
import copy
for i in sequence:
    lineage_1.append(copy.copy(i))
for k in sequence:
    lineage_2.append(copy.copy(k))
```

this will make copies of the sublists of `sequence` so that you don't have this aliasing issue. (If the real code has deeper nesting, you can use `copy.deepcopy` instead of `copy.copy`.)

Answer (score 2):

You have to make a deep copy (or shallow copy suffices in this case) when you append. Else `lineage_1[0][0]` and `lineage_2[0][0]` reference the same object.

```
from copy import deepcopy
for i in sequence:
   lineage_1.append(deepcopy(i))
for k in sequence:
   lineage_2.append(deepcopy(k))
```

See also: http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html

Comment: +1 but in addition you don't need to do the append loop if you use deepcopy. For example, lineage_1 = deepcopy(sequence) is enough.

Comment: true, it certainly is shorter. Just wanted to point out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this simple example:

```
>>> aa = [1, 2, 3]
>>> bb = aa
>>> bb[0] = 999
>>> aa
[999, 2, 3]
```

What happened here?

"Names" like `aa` and `bb` simply *reference* the list, the same list. Hence when you change the list through `bb`, `aa` sees it as well. Using `id` shows this in action:

```
>>> id(aa)
32343984
>>> id(bb)
32343984
```

Now, this is exactly what happens in your code:

```
for i in sequence:
    lineage_1.append(i)
for k in sequence:
    lineage_2.append(k)
```

You append references to *the same lists* to `lineage_1` and `lineage_2`.